# Configuring the url for facet api and pretty path

Tags: commerce, search

Use Drupal 7, Drupal Commerce, Search_api, [Facetapi](http://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi), [facetapi_pretty_path](http://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_pretty_paths).

There menu directory, built on the basis of a dictionary "catalog". When you select a block appears with the selection of facets.

The current URL = domain / category / blabla / 113, and the url at the facets - domain / category / blabla / 113? F [0] = field_firstfield: 103, domain / category / blabla / 113? F [0] = field_secondfield: 126.

So far, so good.

I turn prettypath. and instead of the domain / category / blabla / 113? f [0] = field_firstfield: 103 url formed domain / taxonomy / term / 113 / field_firstfield / data-103.

Why that takes crude prettypath term path (taxonomy / term / 113), rather than to substitute the alias (category / blabla / 113).

1) How to make the url for facets with an alias

2) How to make this way: domain / category / blabla / 113 / options = 102-108-220, where 102, 108, 220 - it was going taxonomy terms.

Thank you.